# Spring Data Flow support for Java/OpenJDK-11 Apps (Source, Processor , Sink)

Tags: spring, spring-cloud-dataflow

I have a Spring Data Flow Local setup. I am able to register example (usage-cost-stream-rabbit) rabbitmq Apps and create a stream as well. This example is working. But when I upgrade this example (Source, Processor & Sink) to Java-11 (OpenJDK-11), stream is not deploying, it says Failed. I have also tried upgrading the Spring Boot version to 2.2.6-RELEASE but the same result.

SDF Versions I used for Local setup:
1. spring-cloud-skipper-server-2.4.1.RELEASE
2. spring-cloud-dataflow-server-2.5.1.RELEASE

Please help me here. If anybody faced this issue. Is it because of OpenJDK-11 support? Any suggestions will be helpful.

Please find the stderr.log:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: io/spring/dataflow/sample/usagecostprocessor/UsageCostProcessorApplication has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:93)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:46)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51)
```

Comment: Can you share the stdout log file for the app that failed?

Comment: The stream is comming as Failed but not further info available, just a status loading icon comming. where can I find the stdout logs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the Java -version on your system, it should be java 11,
If not , then you must set JAVA_HOME to jdk-11
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pUxCM.png)